# Trying to dual boot ubuntu and Windows 10, but due to a grub problem that I may have caused I can't access Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am new to Linux and trying to set up a dual boot with windows 10 on my laptop.

I installed Ubuntu from of my flash drive, and because it wasn't able to detect my OS I had to manually partition my hard drive.

After successfully installing Ubuntu I found that my computer only booted into it and did not show the option to switch to Windows.

I looked up my problem online and saw [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-change-boot-order-set-default-boot-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-15-04-linux-mint-or-other-derivatives) guide, which said to install grub customizer and change the order that things boot in.

Since I didn't see Windows as an option, I instead set my BIOS as the first thing to boot into. Now I can use BIOS to access Windows, but when I set Ubuntu as my default OS it just goes right back into BIOS.

To clarify, I would love it if somebody could explain how to have the menu when my computer starts that allows me to pick my OS, and also how to make stop grub from making running Ubuntu instead run BIOS.

Comment: Please try `sudo update-grub` when in Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try pressing the Shift key on boot?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boot into a live session of Ubuntu from your USB and install Boot-Repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Follow the directions at that link and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? This worked for me when I had this problem. Maybe I'll think twice before trying to offer up help again.